# Add two Queries

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

Merry Christmas!

I do have an question following to add two doctrine queries in symfony 1.4

```
    $q1 = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('order o')
            ->innerJoin('o.shop s ')
            ->innerJoin('o.customer c')
            ->where('o.id = ?', $this->orderid_hashed)
                    ->fetchOne();
    $testid = 19;
    $q2 = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('shopemployee se')
            ->where('se.id = ?', $testid);

    $this->q_all = $q1+$q2;
```

So this is working, I guess. But how do I save now something in one of these tables. For example:

```
$this->q_all -> setOrder()-> setId('123');
or
$this->q_all -> setShopemployee()-> setId('123');
```

This above is not working. How can I do this? Thanks in advance!!!

Craphunter

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. do you want to add a new object to the array,  or modify an existing one?

Answer (score 2):

Why you don't using merge() in doctrine?

```
$data = array('name' => 'jimbob');

$User->Doctrine::getTable('User')->find(1);

$User->merge($data);

$User->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I messed up actually a query. It is a stupid question!